# How to execute this array (jQuery Ajax)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP script that returns an object with 4 records:

```
$obj = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'idCliente'=>$idCliente,
    'arquivo'=>$arquivo,
    'titulo'=>$titulo,
    'descricao'=>$descricao,
    'data' => $datacadastro
    );
```

I need to show the records one by one in a HTML. I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to write this code for 3 days, so I decided to ask.

```
<div>
    ID:
    IDCliente:
    Arquivo:
    Titulo:
    Descricao:
    Data:
</div>
<div>
    ID:
    IDCliente:
    Arquivo:
    Titulo:
    Descricao:
    Data:
</div>
<div>
    ID:
    IDCliente:
    Arquivo:
    Titulo:
    Descricao:
    Data:
</div>
<div>
    ID:
    IDCliente:
    Arquivo:
    Titulo:
    Descricao:
    Data:
</div>
```

How to proceed? I have it:

```
$.ajax ({   type: "POST", 
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/php_functions.php",
    data: {idClienteDocumentos: idClienteDocumentos, ajax: "true"},
    success: function(result){
```

I have this code but it's not working.

```
var campos = ['arquivo', 'idCliente', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'arquivo', 'data'];
var tabela = $('<div id="tabela"></div>');
resultado.forEach(function (linha) {
    var linhaDiv = $('<div></div>');
    linha.forEach(function (campo, index) {
        $('<div></div>').addClass(campos[index]).text(campo).appendTo(linhaDiv);
    });
    linhaDiv.appendTo(tabela);
});
```

Comment: You can add HTML to the DOM using methods like `.append`.  You can also create DOM elements in jquery using the `<` syntax, like `$("<div>")`

Comment: You mean you're looking for a way to translate PHP arrays into JavaScript Object Notation (or JSON)? A function like [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) would be handy...

Comment: Can you show me how it would. Thanks for your help and sorry if my english is not so technical.

Comment: Is your AJAX call returning the correct JSON and you want to know how to create the HTML? Or have you not even figured out how to send back JSON from PHP?

Comment: `json_encode` its ok in php.

Comment: @juan-mendes my AJAX call returning the correct JSON and I want to know how to create the HTML.

Comment: Just want to say, being a new user +1 for not just writing another 'how do I code' question and actually posting your source.

Comment: @marcosvinicius You need to parse the json results, while there is result, you append new html elements to your html page with the data of the json array.

Comment: **Show me pleeeease.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script could be:

```
$obj = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'idCliente'=>$idCliente,
    'arquivo'=>$arquivo,
    'titulo'=>$titulo,
    'descricao'=>$descricao,
    'data' => $datacadastro
    );
$result = array('results' => $obj);
echo json_encode($result); die;
```

Your jQuery could be:

```
$.ajax ({   type: "POST", 
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/php_functions.php",
    data: {idClienteDocumentos: idClienteDocumentos, ajax: "true"},
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response.results.id)
      $("#main_div").append(response.results.id);
    }
});
```

This is just an example script, you can modify according to your needs.

If you have multidimensional array then you can iterate through each records via loop as shown below:

Php Code:

```
$obj[0] = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'idCliente'=>$idCliente,
    'arquivo'=>$arquivo,
    'titulo'=>$titulo,
    'descricao'=>$descricao,
    'data' => $datacadastro
    );
$obj[1] = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'idCliente'=>$idCliente,
    'arquivo'=>$arquivo,
    'titulo'=>$titulo,
    'descricao'=>$descricao,
    'data' => $datacadastro
    );
$result = array('results' => $obj);
echo json_encode($result); die;
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax ({   type: "POST", 
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/php_functions.php",
        data: {idClienteDocumentos: idClienteDocumentos, ajax: "true"},
        success: function(response){
          $.each(response.results, function(i, item) {
           console.log(item.id);
           //You can append data to HTML div
           $("#main_div").append(item.id);
          });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You have not forgotten the loop? In the console appears only the first array object. Very thanks. This is my very problem, the loop.

Comment: WINNNNNNN ... I had some difficulties to run your script because it was missing the php "while" to pick up the items dynamically. I studied the code and implemented your script a bit, I ended up getting solve with the help of 96% of your script. Congratulations and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with the code that you've tried. First, `linha.forEach`. `linha` is an object, but `forEach` iterates over arrays. You want `for...in` to iterate over objects.

Second, you're never adding `tabela` to your document. So even if everything else was working perfectly (and it almost is), you'll never see the result.

```
var campos = ['arquivo', 'idCliente', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'arquivo', 'data'];
var tabela = $('<div id="tabela"></div>');
resultado.forEach(function (linha) {console.log(linha);
var linhaDiv = $('<div></div>');

for(var prop in linha)
{
    $('<div></div>').addClass(''+prop+'').text(prop+': '+linha[prop]).appendTo(linhaDiv);
}

linhaDiv.appendTo(tabela);
tabela.appendTo('html');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ3Jq/)

Now, the only issue with this is that it does not capitalize the label text like you have in your example. If you want that, I'd do it a bit differently...

```
var tabela = $('<div id="tabela"></div>');
$.each(resultado, function(){console.log(this);
    $(tabela).append("<div>ID:"+this.id+"<br/>IDCliente:"+this.idCliente+"<br/>Arquivo:"+this.arquivo+"<br/>Titulo:"+this.titulo+"<br/>Descricao:"+this.descricao+"<br/>Data:"+this.data+"<br/></div>"); 
});
tabela.appendTo('html');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ3Jq/2/)

The final thing I'd say is that you have `success: function(result){` and then `resultado.forEach`. You should either have `result` in both places or `resultado` in both places.